# Can I use cron to run long processes or services?

Tags: cron

I need to have some processes start when the computer boots and run forever. These are not actually daemons, ie. they do not fork or demonize but they do not exit. I am currently using cron to start them using the @reboot directive like this:

```
@reboot /path/to/myProcess >>/logs/myProcess.log
```

Could this cause any problems with the cron daemon? I thought I could try nohup ... & to detach the new process from cron, like this:

```
@reboot nohup /path/to/myProcess >>/logs/myProcess.log &
```

Is this required at all?

Is there some other, preferred method to start processes at system boot? I know all Linux distributions provide config files and means to run a program as a service but I am looking for a method that is not Linux distribution specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.somacon.com/p38.php

This article answers my question. It suggests that running daemons this way spawns two extra processes, a cron and a shell process, that live for as long as your daemon.

I tested this with linux and following the instructions I was able to get rid of the cron process but not the zombie shell process.